# Does the VB.NET "If" operator cause boxing?

Tags: vb.net, ternary-operator, boxing

Those of us who've worked in VB/VB.NET have seen code similar to this abomination:

```
Dim name As String = IIf(obj Is Nothing, "", obj.Name)
```

I say "abomination" for three simple reasons:

1. `IIf` is a **function**, all of whose parameters are evaluated; hence if `obj` is nothing in the above call then a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown. This is unexpected behavior for someone who's accustomed to short-circuited ternary operators in languages like C#.
2. **Because** `IIf` is a function, it thus incurs the overhead of a function call. Again, though this isn't a big deal, it just doesn't feel right to someone who expects for it to behave as a ternary operation intrinsic to the language.
3. `IIf` is non-generic and therefore accepts parameters of type `Object`, which means the following call boxes (I believe) a total of three integers:

   `' boxes 2nd and 3rd arguments as well as return value '`
   `Dim value As Integer = IIf(condition, 1, -1)`

Now, in some more recent version of VB.NET (I'm not sure what the number is), the `If` operator was introduced, which works exactly the same way as the `IIf` function but (as I understand it) without the same shortcomings. That is to say, it **does** provide short-circuiting and it **is** an intrinstic VB operation. However, I'm not sure about the last part. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) doesn't seem to indicate whether `If` boxes its arguments or not. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main thing is that you correctly identified the new `If` as an *operator* rather than a function.  It is also typesafe and therefore does not need boxing, and is a direct mapping to the conditional/ternary/? operator in C/C++/C#/Java/etc

Even without the new operator, you can get some improvement in VB.Net with this code:

```
Public Shared Function IIf(Of T)(ByVal Expression As Boolean, ByVal TruePart As T, ByVal FalsePart As T) As T
    If Expression Then Return TruePart Else Return FalsePart
End Function
```

Comment: I noticed in the blog of some developer on the VB.NET team (forget who) that they had considered doing this, actually -- providing a generic version of `IIf`. I'm glad they went the route they did, since the generic version would fix the boxing issue but would still not provide short-circuiting (or else it would be pretty confusing to have a short-circuited intrinsic language feature disguised as a generic method).

Answer (score 11):

Joel beat me to an answer, but here is a sample program and the generated IL that demonstrates that If() passes through to the IL's underlying ternary operator without boxing.

```
Public Class Test
    Public Sub New()
        Dim rnd = New Random()
        Dim result As Integer = If(rnd.Next(1000) < 500, 1, -1)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see the IL has no 'box' statement.

```
.method public specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 result,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Random rnd)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    L_0007: nop 
    L_0008: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Random::.ctor()
    L_000d: stloc.1 
    L_000e: ldloc.1 
    L_000f: ldc.i4 0x3e8
    L_0014: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Random::Next(int32)
    L_0019: ldc.i4 500
    L_001e: blt.s L_0023
    L_0020: ldc.i4.m1 
    L_0021: br.s L_0024
    L_0023: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0024: stloc.0 
    L_0025: ldloc.0 
    L_0026: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    L_002b: nop 
    L_002c: nop 
    L_002d: ret 
}
```

Given the same program but using the older IIf() function, the following IL is produced.  You can see both the boxing, and the function call overhead:

```
.method public specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 result,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Random rnd)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    L_0007: nop 
    L_0008: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Random::.ctor()
    L_000d: stloc.1 
    L_000e: ldloc.1 
    L_000f: ldc.i4 0x3e8
    L_0014: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Random::Next(int32)
    L_0019: ldc.i4 500
    L_001e: clt 
    L_0020: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0021: box int32
    L_0026: ldc.i4.m1 
    L_0027: box int32
    L_002c: call object [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction::IIf(bool, object, object)
    L_0031: call int32 [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions::ToInteger(object)
    L_0036: stloc.0 
    L_0037: ldloc.0 
    L_0038: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    L_003d: nop 
    L_003e: nop 
    L_003f: ret 
}
```