# Why won't this work as an IIF function, but will as an IF Statement?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5, if-statement, iif-function

The following works:

```
If 1=1
    rdoYes.checked = True
Else
    rdoNo.checked = True
End If
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
IIF(1=1, rdoYes.checked = True, rdoNo.checked = True)
```

Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

Comment: Apologies I meant to vote to close as a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428959/using-vb-net-iif-i-get-nullreferenceexception

Comment: For anyone coming from google a solution to this problem: http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/2012/10/29/SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-IIf-Function-Evaluating-True-And-False-Parameters.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does "work"; it just doesn't do what you want.

`IIf` in VB.NET is a **function** ([don't use it, **ever**, by the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409893/does-the-vb-net-if-operator-cause-boxing)), which takes these parameters:

1. A `Boolean` condition to check
2. An `Object` to return if the condition is `True`
3. A different `Object` to return if the condition is `False`

In your usage, your condition is `1 = 1`; then your two other parameters are `rdoYes.Checked = True` and `rdoNo.Checked = True`, both `Boolean` expressions from the VB compiler's perspective (so, really, they're equivalent to the simpler `rdoYes.Checked` and `rdoNo.Checked`).

Remember that in VB.NET, the `=` sign is *only* an assignment *if it is on its own line*. This is how the compiler distinguishes between statements such as `x = 5` and `If x = 5 Then`.

This is not directly related to your question, but you should also be aware that `IIf` is deprecated and you should almost *always* favor `If` instead:

```
' Let us just suppose it made sense to write this: '
' Notice the If instead of IIf. '
Dim result = If(1 = 1, rdoYes.Checked, rdoNo.Checked)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `IIF()` function will *return* something based on what you enter for the first parameter. Since VB.Net doesn't differ between `=` as in assignment and `=` as in comparison (`==` in many other languages), the second statement is ambiguous.

---

You can do this with using late binding (delegates in VB.Net):

```
(Function(c) InlineAssignHelper(c.Checked, true)).Invoke(IIf(1 = 1, chkYes, chkNo))

  Private Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
  End Function
```

Comment: I added an example how this cán be achieved in VB.Net

Comment: I believe it's actually *not* ambiguous; it **is** the comparison (the `=` symbol is only ever treated as assignment when it is by itself as an expression). Notice that the OP's code does *compile*; it just doesn't *do* what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Because `IIf` takes expressions and returns a result of one of them, and `rdoYes.checked = True` is not an expression and cannot be returned.

Comment: It is an expression, but VB.Net can't know if you're comparing or setting the value.

Comment: You can solve this by late binding :), `Iif(1=1, Function(f) rdoYes.checke

Answer (score 1):

`iif` doesn't do what you think it does -- the important part is the return from it, so you might be able to do:

```
iif(1=1, rdoYes, rdoNo).checked = True
```

(I'm not sure that's valid VB ... it's been more than a decade since I've had to code in it)

Comment: valid Vb would probably be more like ctype(iif(1=1, rdoYes, rdoNo), radiobutton).checked = true. Thanks :)