# VB.net: Setting "NULL" to a property by condition?

Tags: vb.net, object, null, properties

Why below code has error in VB.net 2008?

```
Dim Object1 As New Class1

Object1.SetId = If(rbSet.Checked = True, Convert.ToInt32(txtSetId.Text.Trim()), DBNull.Value)
```

What I'm trying is to set a property of an object by a condition.

Comment: What data type is the `SetId` property, and what is the error message?

Comment: Is the operator not IIF in VB.NET?

Comment: `If` is new in 2008, and has the same semantics as the C# `?:` operator.

Comment: @The_Butcher: [If is way better than IIf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409893/does-the-vb-net-if-operator-cause-boxing).

Answer (score 2):

Use **Nothing**

```
Object1.SetId = If(rbSet.Checked = True, Convert.ToInt32(txtSetId.Text.Trim()), Nothing)
```