# vb.net iif condition in linq query where clause

Tags: vb.net, linq, sharepoint-2010

Whats wrong with the below query, I am getting this error:
***Nullable object must have a value.***

```
  Dim subscriptionUsers = From inv In dataContext.Invoices.ToList Join u In dataContext.Users _
                                    On inv.Subscription Equals u.Subscription _
                                    Where inv.Id.Value = invoiceID _
                                    And Not u.Fund.Title.Contains("AGM") _
                                    And DirectCast(IIf(Not u.EndDate.HasValue, IIf(u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value, True, False), _
                                                    IIf((u.StartDate.Value >= inv.StartDate.Value And u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value) Or _
                                                (u.EndDate.Value >= inv.StartDate.Value And u.EndDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value) Or _
                                                (u.StartDate.Value < inv.StartDate.Value And u.EndDate.Value > inv.EndDate.Value), True, False)), Boolean) _
                                Group By Key = u.Fund.Title Into Group _
                                Select Fund = Key, UsersCount = Group.Count, Users = Group.ToList, _
                                SubFunds = (From a In dataContext.Allocations Where a.Fund.Title = Key Select a.Department.Title Distinct)
```

If I remove the u.EndDate.Value in the condition then it works fine.

Here is the stack trace:

at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
   at SDBReports.InvoiceAllocationReportUserControl._Lambda$__4(VB$AnonymousType_0`2 $VB$It)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Lookup`2.Create[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`4.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()

p.s. I have used SPMetal to generate the entity classes on SharePoint lists.

For more clarity:

do not get confused with u.EndDate.Value and inv.EndDate.Value

here is the true part for u.EndDate.Hasvalue:

```
 IIf((u.StartDate.Value >= inv.StartDate.Value And u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value) Or _
                                                (u.EndDate.Value >= inv.StartDate.Value And u.EndDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value) Or _
                                                (u.StartDate.Value < inv.StartDate.Value And u.EndDate.Value > inv.EndDate.Value), True, False)
```

and here is the false part

```
IIf(u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value, True, False)
```

Comment: I would assume those dates are nullable, and that one of them *is* null. Accessing `Value` on a null nullable is a no-no.

Comment: I am checking if the date field has any value right? u.EndDate.HasValue

Comment: The `IIf` function does not short-circuit. [Use `If` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409893/does-the-vb-net-if-operator-cause-boxing)

Comment: Why are you using `IIf(u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value, True, False)` rather than just the expression `u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I was tell him the same for an improvement, but that wouldn't still fix the error.

Comment: @PedroC88: Indeed - but simplifying the code may help to make it easier to see the wood for the trees :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use `If` instead of `IIf`. This is short-circuited (like C#’s conditional operator) and will work because the conditions are *only* evaluated *if* `HasValue` is `True`. `IIf` is deprecated. Never use it.
- Furthermore, an expression like `If(condition, True, False)` is nonsensical. Replace it with just `condition`.
- Finally, you need to use `AndAlso` instead of `And` – once again, for short-circuiting to happen. In fact, *always* use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` in conditionals. Use `And` and `Or` *only* when doing bit operations.
- The `DirectCast` is also unnecessary.

This leaves us with a much simplified expression:

```
If(Not u.EndDate.HasValue, u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value), _
    (u.StartDate.Value >= inv.StartDate.Value AndAlso u.StartDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value) OrElse _
    (u.EndDate.Value >= inv.StartDate.Value AndAlso u.EndDate.Value <= inv.EndDate.Value) OrElse _
    (u.StartDate.Value < inv.StartDate.Value AndAlso u.EndDate.Value > inv.EndDate.Value))
```

But this expression is still much too complex. You should split this up but first assigning the values inside the nullables to some temporary variable using `Let` inside the query.

Comment: I believe the OP still has it wrong, though. He's checking `Not u.EndDate.HasValue`, and then using `u.EndDate.Value` in the `TruePart` argument. That's guaranteed not to work, right? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Dan I can’t be sure of course – but the OP is using a *different* `EndDate`, namely of `inv` instead of `u`.

Comment: @Dan Let me think. Uhm, maybe because the expression is ridiculously complex and completely confusing?

Answer (score 1):

IIF evaluates both results, even though it only returns one. So if one result would cause an exception (like accessing .Value of a nullable when there is none) you will get an error even if you check for .HasValue at the beginning of the IIF

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the IIF evaluation both parts.

Try some code like this:

```
IIF (True, msgbox("True"), msgbox("false"))
```

You'll get two message boxes show up.  One that says "True" and one that says "false".  Even though it's clear you should only trigger the True section.